# What are these connectors used for on the plane?

Tags: air-travel, airlines

What are these connectors used for in one spot of the passenger seating area of a 737?

On a recent flight I saw what a feature I have never seen before above my seat near the reading lights and air vents.

[image: picture of mysterious feature above passenger seat]

I apologize for the low quality picture. I put my phone in selfie mode and took the picture from the tray table to avoid acting like a weirdo on the plane.

These two small round black spring loaded covers can be easily opened by pressing and holding the tab, then they spring close when you release. Underneath them is a hole that looks similar to a 1/4" audio jack.
The label says "MEDICAL COMMUNICATION CREW USE ONLY"

I did not notice if one of them was slightly larger than the other, a la headsets in small planes.

It is above row 5 on the right hand side of the airplane. I looked around and saw nothing similar ahead or behind me or on the left side. I have never seen this before on different airlines or models of plane.

This is on a Southwest Airlines 737-800 N8612K, a fairly new but not brand new aircraft in scheduled passenger service.

Comment: Please see this related question on Aviation: [How are the "medical communication" headset sockets on some airliners used?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12776/how-are-the-medical-communication-headset-sockets-on-some-airliners-used)

Comment: @GregHewgill well that question certainly is about the same connectors! Although the rationale and explanation is very lacking. I've been on board aircraft where a passenger has a medical emergency at least half dozen times in the past 10 years and never have I seen a flight attendant using a headset. They just talk to another FA at the nearest galley who is on the intercom with the pilots. Are passengers with medical problems required to sit in approximately row 5 on the right side? Of course not! The explanations in those answers are exasperatingly illogical.

Comment: @AldusBumblebore What did the crew say when you asked them?

Comment: @AldusBumblebore obviously the plan is that in certain cases the patient is to be moved to the row with the connectors, so in those cases the passenger is in fact supposed to be sitting in that row.

Comment: @AldusBumblebore It sounds like your question is answered, then. Though it also sounds like you additionally want to ask "why do flight attendants not use the communications port during medical emergencies", which would make a decent new question.

Comment: @AldusBumblebore Remember that airlines carry passengers with medical needs. I've seen people on stretcher where seatbacks was removed to accomodate the person.